# How to simplify with topojson API?

Tags: topojson

So I have no problem simplifying using `topojson` from the command line using the `-s` flag, however, I can't figure out how to do it from the `node` module.

I see a `topojson.simplify()` method, but I can't figure out how it works as there is no documentation.

Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the simplification tests for topojson, I was able to figure out how to use toposjson.simplify(), but I can't fully claim to know whats going on. You can see the tests on [the topojson github](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/blob/master/test/simplify-test.js).

Basically topojson.simplify takes a topology input and has 2 possible options for simplification, "retain-proportion" and "minimum-area", you can also pass the coordinate system, aka "cartesian" or "spherical", although it can be inferred under most circumstances.

examples:

```
output = topojson.simplify(topology,{"minimum-area": 2,"coordinate-system": "spherical"});
output =topojson.simplify(topology,{"retain-proportion: 2,"coordinate-system": "spherical"});
```

I am not really sure exactly what the values you pass into these options mean, however higher values tends to produce more simplification. As a note, retain proportion often returns invalid topologies when passed LineStrings, that may be as intended.

Additionally  using the quantization option in topojson.topology can be used to create a smaller, simpler output and may be the best solution to some similar use cases and also doesn't have any clearly documented server API examples anywhere so:

```
//very simplified, small output
topojson.topology({routes: routesCollection},{"quantization":100});
//very unfiltered, large output
topojson.topology({routes: routesCollection},{"quantization":1e8});
```

note: the default quantization is 10000 (1e4), so anything less than 10000 will create a smaller output and vice versa.